# How to make sure that Enterprise library Logger.Write() worked?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, exception, enterprise-library

I am using Enterprise library 5.0 for Logging mechanism. I am using flat file and DB listeners. I want to make sure that the errors were logged into the db and in case some error occurred while doing the same the error should automatically start logging into the flat files. I guess we need to switch to Flat file Logging automatically in case of an exception.

```
loggingConfiguration name="Logging" tracingEnabled="true" defaultCategory="DatabaseLogging"
```

But I believe the `defaultCateogory` is a read only property for the section. How I can do it programatically?

Comment: :-D Thats my last name ! I would appreciate your help on the problem :-)

Answer (score 1):

You may consider to use Unit test, to make sure the will log the errors in all different scenario  , thats why we have unit test :)

Unit testing is all about automation, so you need to be able to automate the validation of log entries.

also you can consider using Priority. (it is used to filter Log Entries, only those above the “Minimum Priority” are processed), so it something has high priority , it may go to the flat file as well.

Hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks for a quick response, If we automate using VSTS 2010(automation tool) I guess the only way to check the log in the DB is to make an expensive db call and check if the record exists. It would be great if the logger.write method throws some exception in case of any error occured while looging to db.

Comment: @Bose_geek, you could create/mock custom trace listeners that you can query to validate that that the appropriate messages were logged.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759141/programmatic-configuration-of-enterprise-library-logging-block for an Enterprise Library 4 example.  The configuration would be different but the approach similar.

Answer (score 0):

There is a special category called Logging Errors & Warnings which you should hook up to a listener to be notified when your normal logging category fails. You should also put the listeners on your normal category in order from most likely to work to most likely to fail, because writing to the listeners will stop once there is a failure.

Also, default category is not read only. That is the category that logs will be written to if you do not specify a category when creating a log entry. Logging errors will not be written to that category however. Those only go to the Logging Errors & Warnings special category.

Comment: So from what i can understand is that(correct me if I am wrong), the Logging Errors & Warnings will work in those scenarios where our normal category will fail. well, when i tried to set the default category value from the program it was throwing an exception that its read only(I was getting the logging configuration as section though)

Comment: Logs are sent to Logging Errors & Warnings when a normal category matches, but an exception occurred while calling a trace listener. When no category matches, they are sent to the default category.

You can either set the default category in the configuration file, or use the [fluent API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664363(v=pandp.50).aspx) to configure Enterprise Library. It may be possible to combine these approaches but I have never attempted to. Directly changing the configuration section in code will not work.